# How can I get activatedRoute in effect for nav relativeTo?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have different buttons navigating to the same page

```
this.router.navigate([`geopoint/${id}/edit`], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: {id}});
```

I would like to pass the activatedRoute in a dispatch but the readOnly is triggered. How do I pass the activated route to my effect ?

setup

```
error @angular-devkit/architect 0.900.6 @angular-devkit/build-angular 0.900.6 @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr 0.900.6 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer 0.900.6 @angular-devkit/build-webpack 0.900.6 @angular-devkit/core 9.0.6 @angular-devkit/schematics 9.0.6 @angular/cdk 9.1.3 @angular/material 9.1.3 @ngtools/webpack 9.0.6 @schematics/angular 9.0.6 @schematics/update 0.900.6 ng-packagr 9.0.3 rxjs 6.5.4 typescript 3.7.5 webpack 4.41.2
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a UrlTree and define that as a prop on your action instead of trying to pass in activatedRoute.

```
export const navigationAction = createAction(
    "[App] Navigate",
    props<{
        destination: UrlTree;
    }>()
);

const destination = this.router.createUrlTree(["your", "paths"], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
this.store.dispatch(
    navigationAction({
        destination: destination,
    })
);

navigate$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(
    () =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(navigationAction),
            tap((action) => this.router.navigateByUrl(action.destination))
        ),
    {dispatch: false}
);
```

Comment: Same. readonly error. `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'parent' of object '[object Object]'`